# Cannot retrieve cookie value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

Am storing and retreiving the cookie using the coding

```
public static void SetCookie(string key, string value, int dayExpires)
    {
        HttpCookie encodedCookie = HttpSecureCookie.Encode(new HttpCookie(key, value));
        encodedCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(dayExpires);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(key);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(encodedCookie);
    }
    public static string GetCookie(string key)
    {
        string value = string.Empty;
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            // For security purpose, we need to encrypt the value.
            HttpCookie decodedCookie = HttpSecureCookie.Decode(cookie);
            value = decodedCookie.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            SetCookie("currency", "GBP", 1);
            if (key.ToUpper() == "CURRENCY")
                value = "GBP";
            else if (key.ToUpper() == "COUNTRYCODE")
                value = "GB";
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

am able to store the cookie and also when i try to get the value of currency from the cookie using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key]` where key has currency am getting the value as ""

in the image below you can have the look at the cookies stored
[image: cookie quick watch]

here you can see that you can currency repeated twice. In key [4] currency is "" where as i have my cookie value in key [6]. Any help why the currency is repeated twice when i am removing the key and then adding the key in the immediate lines.

For test purpose i have placed the set and get in the immediate lines. code below

```
CookieStore.SetCookie("currency", CurrencyCode, 1);
string currencycookie=CookieStore.GetCookie("currency");
```

Ultimately i must have only one currency where i have the unique key there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the key like this will not help you , remove the cookie set in the client browser. Either you have to set the expiry date in the past for the existing key. Better solution is to check if the key is available update the value of the cookie rather than removing and adding it.

```
      if (Request.Cookies[key] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies[key].Value = "NEW VAalue"                
        }
        else
         // create the new cookie key.
```

See my updated code with logic of removing and adding the new value

```
      if (Request.Cookies["Test"] == null)
        {
            HttpCookie testCookie = new HttpCookie("Test");
            testCookie.Value = "1";
            testCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(testCookie);
        }
        else
        {
            var c = Request.Cookies["Test"];
            c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
            Response.Cookies.Add(c);
            HttpCookie testCookie = new HttpCookie("Test");
            testCookie.Value = "2";
            testCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(testCookie);
        }
```

I have updated your method.

```
      public static void SetCookie(string key, string value, int dayExpires)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies[key] != null)
        {
            var c = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];
            c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(c);
        }
        HttpCookie encodedCookie = HttpSecureCookie.Encode(new HttpCookie(key, value));
        encodedCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(dayExpires);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(encodedCookie);
    }
```

Comment: ok thanks bro. but is there no method of removing the unwanted cookie?

Comment: @Saurabh you have to set the expiry date in the past to remove the unwanted key and then add the new one

Comment: in the first currency key am not adding any thing to it but gettng expiry as {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} where as second key am getting my stored value. i cant set expiry to this first one. @Devesh

Comment: @Saurabh I have updated my answer with one test code that is working fine in my system. it is removing the old key and adding the new one with new value. Just try

Comment: @Saurabh After you have set the expiry in the past of the existing key add it again in the Response and then create the new one with the value and add new one also to the response. See my code carefully.See my updated response . I have modified your method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43309/discussion-between-saurabh-and-devesh)